# How can I send a image over the network in XNA?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, xbox360

Making a randomly generated noise image, was wondering possible solutions of how to send it to other players.

I know the best method is to just send the seed, which is probably the solution I will go with, but I was curious as to if there is a good method to send an image across the XNA/C#/Xbox networks.

Comment: Seed would be the way to go, If all clients are the same, using a seed would be much more effecient

Comment: Yes. I know, like I said. I was curious as to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could technically serialize the Texture2D via a stream and send a Byte Array over the network.  Then deserialize the data on the other end.  This might be useful on something like a dedicated server with special pictures or custom maps that you want to pass to everyone without making them go get them somewhere.  For the record, in your case I agree that seed is the way to go, if for no other reason than because you're lucky enough to have that options, and sending an int is much easier than a byte array.  That being said, try something like this:

```
Texture2D image = Content.Load<Texture2D>("test"); //Or rather however you ended up making your texture
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
image.SaveAsJpeg(stream, image.Width, image.Height);
byte[] data = stream.ToArray();
```

Then you can pass data over the network and deserialize it on the other side.